# How do I mount file as ConfigMap inside DaemonSet?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, configmap

I have following nginx config file (named *nginx-daemonset.conf*) that I want to use inside my Daemonset:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my-nginx;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a ConfigMap using following command: `kubectl create configmap nginx2.conf --from-file=nginx-daemonset.conf`

I have following DaemonSet (*nginx-daemonset-deployment.yml*) inside which I am trying to mount this ConfigMap - so the previous nginx config file is used:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-daemonset
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-daemonset
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx-daemonset
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx-daemonset
    spec:
      tolerations:
      # this toleration is to have the daemonset runnable on master nodes
      # remove it if your masters can't run pods
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx2-conf
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      volumes:
      - name: nginx2-conf
        configMap:
            name: nginx2.conf
```

I deployed this Daemonset using `kubectl apply -f nginx-daemonset-deployment.yml` but my newly created Pod is crashing with the following error:

*`Error: failed to start container "nginx": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/cd9f6f7b-31db-4ab3-bbc0-189e1d392979/volume-subpaths/nginx2-conf/nginx/0" to rootfs at "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b21ccba23347a445fa40eca943a543c1103d9faeaaa0218f97f8e33bacdd4bb3/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`*

I did another Deployment with different nginx config before and everything worked fine, so the problem is probably somehow related to DaemonSet.

Please, how do I get over this error and mount the config file properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first create your config file as a ConfigMap like nginx-conf:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
data:
  envfile: |
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {

        server {
            listen 80;
            
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://my-nginx;
            }
        }
    }
```

then create your DaemonSet, volumes, configMap and finial y mount volumeMounts with subPath:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
          readOnly: true
          name: nginx-vol
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-vol
        configMap:
          name: nginx-conf
          items:
            - key: envfile
              path: nginx.conf
```

note that for *file mounting* instead of *directory mounting* you must use "path in configMap" and "subPath in volumeMounts".

Comment: I followed your approach and it works! Somehow I still can not clearly understand the main differences between your and my approach, could you please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: your configuration work for directory mounting, but if you want to file mount you must use "path in configMap" and "subPath in volumeMounts".

Comment: What exact line please do you mean by "path in configMap"? I am still confused :/

Comment: "path in configMap in volumes", last line of second code that i sent to answer.